# Tab issue on DocuSign, xPosition and yPosition are there any option?

Tags: tabs, docusignapi

I'm using DocuSign's REST API and so far so I'm successfully sending signature requests, however positioning the DocuSign tabs in my documents is sometimes a pain and requires trial and error. Is using the **xPosition** and **yPosition** properties of the tabs the only option I have for tab placement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DocuSign actually provides a nifty features called "Anchor Tagging" which helps solve this problem.  With Anchor Tagging you can have DocuSign tabs placed in your documents based on the document content itself.  So for instance, if somewhere in your document you need signed you have the text "Please Sign Here" you can anchor to that text and have your tabs placed there without trying to guess the X and Y coordinates.

There's examples of how to this on the [Features -> Stick-eTabs section of DocuSign's Developer Center](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features), just scroll down and see the anchor tagging section.

You have the option of further offsetting from the document text also, like if you want your signature tab to be 1 inch to the right and .5 inches down, for example.  You would send a JSON request body like this:

```
"tabs": {
  "signHereTabs": [
    {
    "anchorString": "Please Sign Here:",
    "anchorXOffset": "1",
    "anchorYOffset": "0.5",
    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
    "anchorUnits": "inches"
    }
  ]
}
```