# DocuSign: How to send a radio group selection in recipient tabs?

Tags: docusignapi

I have radio groups set up in my template and I want to pre-fill these tags using the REST API.

Please don't ask for code and/or request/response dumps. I don't have any code to show and I am asking for this because it is not documented. I want to know what sort of JSON I need to be producing so this is really not about my code or programming language.

---

(Anything below this line is half rant and half describes my failed attempts at finding the documentation for this feature. It might still be useful if somebody else has the exact same problem with me.)

[Here](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Send%20an%20Envelope%20from%20a%20Template.htm) is the documentation for the API I am trying to use. There is an example for `textTabs` but `radioGroupTabs` is not even mentioned here. It is mentioned [here](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Recipients/Signers%20Recipient.htm) but I can't make much out of the `"null"`, obviously I should be sending something other than null.

Moving on, the only useful information I can find on the radio groups is about how to create them in a template, it's [here](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Radio%20Group%20Tab.htm). This page also doesn't mention anything about pre-filling the values for a recipient. But it's linked from [here](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Recipients/Signers%20Recipient.htm) (see `tabs`) anyway. There is a bit of information here:

```
value: if an X, this is the selected radio button. Only one radio button in a group can be selected.
```

And then just before this it says:

```
selected: Sets if this is radio button is selected. Use true/false to show the value is selected or not. Only one radio button can be true.
```

So we learn there are only just two ways to specify a radio widget selected. Of course this applies when you are creating the widget.

Nevertheless I tried to make requests assuming this would also work for pre-filling I got this helpful error message:

```
{
  "errorCode": "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR",
  "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
}
```

When I search the support forum I've found [this](http://community.docusign.com/t5/DocuSign-API-Integration-NET/Using-CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms-with-radio-buttons/m-p/3259/highlight/true#M274), it's not exactly the same with my problem, I'd be happy to be able to set the wrong radio widget selected (as opposed to getting the `UNSPECIFIED_ERROR`) but this post is about the XML API.

I started my frantical search for the new topic button, it is so well placed you can usually find it in less than 10 minutes. I remember I used to go to my profile and then click something there... Then I did what every rational developer would do in the first place and went back to the post URL and read the breadcrumbs; `Dev Zone` section was renamed as `Dev Zone (MOVED TO STACK OVERFLOW - Use tag DocuSignAPI)`. So here I am.

Could anyone please tell where this feature is documented or maybe provide a sample JSON please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've found the correct page for [how to create radio buttons](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Radio%20Group%20Tab.htm), not sure why you're having trouble using that resource.  You've mentioned that's the code to CREATE the radio button tabs and not send them.  That's not correct - the request body to send them is the same exact body only that the **status** property of the request changes from *created* to *sent*.

I just tested sending two radio buttons with the first button selected by default and it worked fine for me.  Here is the full request body I used for my document signature request, this should work for you as well:

```
{
"emailBlurb": "Testing DocuSign radio buttons",
"emailSubject": "Custom PHP script",
"status": "sent",
"documents": [
    {
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "test.pdf"
    }
],
"recipients": {
    "signers": [
        {
            "email": "john.doe@docusign.com",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "tabs": {
                "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                        "xPosition": "100",
                        "yPosition": "200",
                        "documentId": "1",
                        "pageNumber": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "radioGroupTabs": [
                    {
                        "documentId": "1",
                        "groupName": "RadioGroup1",
                        "radios": [
                            {
                                "pageNumber": "1",
                                "selected": "true",
                                "value": "X",
                                "xPosition": "300",
                                "yPosition": "75"
                            },
                            {
                                "pageNumber": "1",
                                "selected": "false",
                                "xPosition": "350",
                                "yPosition": "75"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

To add to this, the above example uses absolute positioning to position the radio buttons on the document.  The other way of specifying tab locations in DocuSign is by using what's called "Anchor Tagging".  With anchor tagging, instead of positioning based on coordinate systems, you can you can position your tabs with respect to document content.  Please see the following two links to learn how to use anchor tagging, it's quite easy to switch to this method:

[Anchor Tagging Introduction - Look at the "Tab Positioning" section](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/stick-etabs)

[Related Stack Overflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417801/tab-issue-on-docusign-xposition-and-yposition-are-there-any-option)

Comment: Is there any other way to specify the radio widget other than providing its coordinates and the page number? It couples the layout of the document and the data tightly.

Comment: I was curious to know if there was any way to refer to a tab without knowing its position (absolute or relative) and page.

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer, please look at the last paragraph and the two links I left at the end...

Comment: Both of the solutions you describe use either absolute or relative positions of tabs. I would like to be able to identify tabs without using the position and page number. I read your answer and your comment. Perhaps you didn't read mine.

Comment: Anchor Tagging is considered "relative" positioning, but it does not use position or page number so I'm not sure why that doesn't work for you?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I still need to know exactly how far from the anchor my tab is positioned. If the tab is moved 1 pixel (or inch or whatever unit you're using) by accident I will fail to prefill the tab and I won't get any notifications. I am trying to, EXACTLY, accomplish writing robust software.

Comment: If I could give a unique identifier to my radio widget (a radio button sharing a radio group with others) then I wouldn't have to depend on it's location in the document. My signing workflow would still function if somebody moved the tab by accident for instance.

Comment: But every tab DOES have a unique identifier already.  Each tab has a tabId field assigned to it.  Try doing this call on one of the envelopes you've created and you'll see tabId field come back... [Get Tab Info for a Recipient](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Get%20Tab%20Information%20for%20a%20Recipient.htm)

Comment: This call is on envelope basis. Is there any way to query (or even better see in the UI) these unique IDs for a given template? If yes, then how should I form my JSON to use these IDs you mentioned instead of coordinages and page numbers?

Comment: So it seems there is no clean way to prefill radio groups. I'll accept this answer but I won't be happy implementing this solution.

Comment: Still unclear what you're asking.  What do you mean by "prefill radio groups"?  Radio buttons are either checked or they are not checked, and the JSON I've provided shows how to start one of them in the group checked.

Comment: Nevermind, it's clear to me that there is no other way than the two you describe in your answer.