# docusign how to configure RadioGroup

Tags: php, docusignapi

I try to insert Radio Buttons to my PDF
I use SignatureHereTabs, DateSignedTabs, TextTabs, CheckBoxTabs and this works fine, but with radio buttons, I don't know how to set all the properties correctly.

my PHP CODE:

```
$radio1 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere();
$radio1->setXPosition("100");
$radio1->setYPosition("215");
$radio1->setDocumentId("1");
$radio1->setPageNumber("1");
$radio1->setRecipientId("1");
$radio1->setTabLabel("labelRadio1");
$radio1->setName("NameRadio1");                     
//$radio1->setGroupName("GroupRadio");          // NOT WORKING
//$radio1->setValue("valueRadio1");             // NOT WORKING

$radio2 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere();
$radio2->setXPosition("130");
$radio2->setYPosition("215");
$radio2->setDocumentId("1");
$radio2->setPageNumber("1");
$radio2->setRecipientId("1");
$radio2->setTabLabel("labelRadio2");
$radio2->setName("NameRadio2");                 
//$radio2->setGroupName("GroupRadio");              // NOT WORKING
//$radio2->setValue("valueRadio2");                 // NOT WORKING

$tabs = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs();
$tabs->setRadioGroupTabs(array($radio1,$radio2));

==>
setGroupName and setValue Not Working 
==>
No buttons appear on the PDF instead CheckBox works fine
```

What's wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please accept/check the best answers for your questions. And upvote all useful answers that you see, including answers for other people's questions. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are incorrectly using using the `SignHere` tabs.

For radio buttons you should use `\DocuSign\eSign\Model\Radio()` SDK [link](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client/blob/master/src/Model/Radio.php)

The radio buttons should then be added to `DocuSign\eSign\Model\RadioGroup()` SDK [link](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client/blob/master/src/Model/RadioGroup.php)

I have updated your code to use `Radio` and `RadioGroup`

```
$radio1 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Radio();
$radio1->setXPosition("100");
$radio1->setYPosition("215");
$radio1->setPageNumber("1");        
$radio1->setValue("valueRadio1");             

$radio2 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Radio();
$radio2->setXPosition("130");
$radio2->setYPosition("215");
$radio2->setPageNumber("1");                     
$radio2->setValue("valueRadio2");        

$radioGroup = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\RadioGroup();
$radioGroup->setDocumentId("1");
$radioGroup->setGroupName("GroupRadio");   
$radioGroup->setRadios(array($radio1,$radio2))

$tabs = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs();
$tabs->setRadioGroupTabs(array($radioGroup));
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18197148/1219543) for the json example when using RadioGroup.

Comment: sorry, but the script stops at  $radio->setDocumentId("1") define before by $document->setDocumentId("1");

Comment: Can you please post your complete script and full error message you are getting.

Comment: the code is too long for the comment.
It is avalaible at http://www.christian-poulin.fr/REST-DOCUSIGN/docusign/code.php
You can rest it at http://www.christian-poulin.fr/REST-DOCUSIGN/docusign/index.php

Comment: Updated my answer as it specified some invalid properties. `DocumentId` and `GroupName` are RadioGroup properties, so moved them. Also removed `TabeLabel` and `Name` from radio.

Comment: The correct code is $radioGroup->setRadios(array($radio1,$radio2));
Other question about text 
http://www.christian-poulin.fr/REST-DOCUSIGN/docusign/code.php
All the commented lines not working. Without this properties the field appears to contains only one character
example at http://www.christian-poulin.fr/REST-DOCUSIGN/docusign/index.php

Comment: You are using `\DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere()` for a text tab. That is incorrect. You have to use the `Text` tab. See [here](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client/blob/ccc86ac37334f34728361d73b2f8c4592225b8d2/src/Model/Text.php)