# Managing large envelopes

Tags: docusignapi

Background: We use the DocuSign SOAP API method CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms for a very clear reason (mainly, we don't want to keep track of page numbers and X/Y coordinates) and we do not want to stop using this api method (unless there is another method that doesn't force us to keep track of page numbers and X/Y coordinates). I mention this before someone happily suggests I use another method.

Problem: We've recently been asked to send large envelopes through the DocuSign api (could exceed 100 mb). I know that DocuSign doesn't place a limit on envelope size, but rather on size of payload per api call when the envelope is created. I think what we need to do is the following, but I am having trouble:

**Step 1**: load up to 50 mb in the templates
**Step 2**: call CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms but set the ActivateEnvelope parameter to False
**Step 3**: load up to another 50 mb in the a new set of templates
**Step 4**: call CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms again but this time set the ActivateEnvelope parameter to True.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? I keep getting an error that says the "TransactionID has already been used." If what I'm trying to do (in general) is possible, any code samples would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Anchor Tags is a viable and easy to use feature that should solve your issue here.  With anchor tags you can still use the `CreateEnvelopeFromTemplateAndForms()` API call but you won't have to specify page numbers or (x,y) coordinates for your DocuSign Stick-eTabs.  Instead, those tabs will get "anchored" to your documents based on content that it finds in the document itself.

For instance, let's say you have a document that needs to be signed and in the document where the signature should go you have the text "Sign Here".  You can have the system place a signature tab close to this "Sign Here" text.  You could have it place it X amount of pixels to the right, or Y inches or cms to the right, etc.

You can add these tabs at the account level, which means they will get applied whenever their corresponding text is found in ANY envelope you create in your account, OR you could add them in your API request so that they are only used on that particular envelope.

For more info please see the following links:

[Previous Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417801/tab-issue-on-docusign-xposition-and-yposition-are-there-any-option)

[Explanation on Dev Center - look at Tab Positioning section](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/stick-etabs)

Comment: You only addressed the background I provided, not my question. Would you please look at the part of my post which I labeled as the "Problem"? I am trying to send the envelope in multiple steps to get around the api upload size limits. Any insights here?

Comment: When you use the `CreateEnvelopeFromTemplateAndForms()` call it sends an envelope from a template that was created through the DocuSign Console.  Why can't you upload the large documents through the Console at design time, then make the corresponding template api calls when needed?  Does it still error out in this case?

Comment: Unfortunately, your statement ("CreateEnvelopeFromTemplateAndForms() ... sends an envelope from a template that was created through the DocuSign Console") is not correct. This api method allows the developer to create a template on-the-fly (at runtime) and send that template in the call to the method. We cannot use hard-coded templates as our PDF payloads are dynamically generated and will frequently not be the same from one scenario to the next.